# How do I update State outside of Render?

Tags: reactjs

From what I understand, this is what Redux is supposed to solve, but for the time being I'm trying to make this work without it.

When I run this, I realize it is stuck in a pattern. When I run `render` it triggers `updateState()` which changes the state, that triggers a re-render, which triggers `updateState()` and so on...

I am getting the error:

```
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition  (such as within render or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to componentWillMount.
```

What does `componentWillMount` do? What would be the best way to structure this so when I call `<CreateRows />` it will update state, but avoid the loop?

```
var CreateRows = React.createClass({
    updateState : function(){
        this.setState({
            'people' : [{'name':'something_else', 'email':'test2@gmail.com'}]
        });
        return (
                <tr>
                    <td>Morgan</td>
                    <td>test@gmail.com</td>
                </tr>

            )
    }

    render: function(){
        return (
            <tbody>
                {this.updateState()}
            </tbody>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not recommended to update state on [render](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#render), but after component has been rendered you can update it for example using *componentDidMount* method:

```
var CreateRows = React.createClass({
    updateState : function(){
        this.setState({
            'people' : [{'name':'something_else', 'email':'test2@gmail.com'}]
        });
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.updateState();
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Morgan</td>
                    <td>test@gmail.com</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        );
    }
});
```